# In what case the throughput ability of a system that can handle two processes would be bigger

Tags: io, dispatcher, multitasking

In what case the throughput ability of a system that can handle two processes would be bigger,1)if them two would be i/o bound or2) the 1st cpu bound and the other i/o bound?

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic because it is not related to a programming problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other things being equal, the second case, because there wouldn't be as much contention for the CPU or the I/O devices.